# Charges in colloidal dispersion

Tags: colloids

How does charge come on dispersion medium in colloidal sols ? (It is said that in electro-osmosis flow of dispersion medium takes because it is also electrically charged, but why ? )

Comment: Have you read about Zeta Potential?